# How to stop a second change event from firing in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm having difficulty trying to work out a way I can update an input field without it in IE8 firing a second change event. In FF 3.6 this code work as I would want.

I thought returning false from the function event handler would stop any further events being fired but it doesn't appear so in IE.

Here's what I have tried so far:

1. Returning false in a live event handler.
2. Used bind and event.stopImmediatePropagation(). Although I would like to use live in the real code I'm using as form elements are being swapped in/out via AJAX calls.
3. Used die and live again before and after the input field update. But I guess this update to the input field occurs after the function has finished.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here? I'm fairly new to JQuery so maybe I've made a silly error :)

Thanks!

Here's some test code to show the problem:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    var counter = 0;

     $(document).ready(function() {


        $('.eventHandler').live('change', handleChangeEvent);

        });

    function handleChangeEvent(event){

        //$('.eventHandler').die();

        $(this).val(counter++);

        //$('.eventHandler').live('change', handleChangeEvent);

        return false;

    }

    </script>

    </head>
        <body>
            <form>
                <input type="text" value="0.00" id="54501" class="eventHandler"/>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Answered my own problem**

Not allowed as a new user to answer my own question for 8 hrs. So will put here for now

Just figured it by explaining the problem more to Dr.Molle. Always the way helps to talk a problem through.

Because the input still had focus when I updated the input field value, when I clicked away it triggers another 'change' event.

So if I remove the focus before updating the input field value it never triggers another event.

I changed the code to this and works as I wanted it to in IE:

```
    var counter = 0;

     $(document).ready(function() {


        $('.eventHandler').unbind('blur').live('change', handleChangeEvent);

        });

    function handleChangeEvent(event){


        $('body').focus();


        $(this).val(counter++);
        event.preventDefault();




        return false;

    }
```

Thanks for your help Dr.Molle, in explaining it more it helped me work it out - Cheers!!!

Answer (score -1):

<strike>You may first unbind the already bound change-events:

`$('.eventHandler').unbind('change').live('change', handleChangeEvent);`</strike>

Comment: Hi thank for reply. Just tried that the unbind as described, but unfortunately still fires the change event when updating the input field.

Comment: Mmmh, if I uncomment the 2 lines in handleChangeEvent, everything works fine, also in IE8. What's the desired behaviour?

Comment: Strange, for me it still does not work when uncommenting those two lines. Initially it appears to work but as soon as you click anywhere else on the page the input losses focus, it triggers another change even. So become stuck in a loop. Ideally would just like to be able to update the input field with a value without trigger another 'change' event. Strange requirement when looking at my example. But in the app I'd like to see the input field cleared and then update with a result. But there are occasions when the user inputs a value and I don't want to update the input.